# @Html.RenderPartial vs jQuery.load()

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Almost everything is in the title.

For me in a ASP.net MVC app, we can render a partial view :

Using Razor :

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("_TestPartial");}
```

or jQuery :

```
//JS
$('#partial-container').load('GetPartial');

//Controller
public ActionResult GetPartial()
{
    return View("_TestPartial");
}
```

Is there any difference ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course there is a difference.

- Serverside: `RenderPartial` embeds the partial directly in the webpage response.
- Clientside: `load` will execute after you have received the webpage response. Then a new request ist started, which is loading the partial.

If you immediately load the Partial, I would go for Serverside, since you can save one request. An exception would be, if the partial takes long time to process and you want to show a response very quickly.

Normaly one would use the Clientside `load` to render some view after a user interaction without loading a whole new page.

Comment: That's exactly what I would like to know (server-side or client-side) ;-) Thanks. I agree for using a server-side at page load for exemple and client-side in case of update...

Answer (score 2):

> You can call the action with a `$.post` or `$.get` and replace the
>   return value of a **html** in the desired Tag.

```
    var Url='@(Url.Action("GetPartial","ControllerName"))';
    $.get( Url, function( data ) {
      $( '#partial-container' ).html( data );
    });
```